# SMS gateway solution without using gsm modem

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel

I want to create a solution like twilio/nexmo which will be capable of sending and receiving messages. With twilio like sms gateway out there in the web we can send and receive messages with custom numbers. Hence I assume they were capable of sending sms messages without the use of a gsm modem( Since, if they are using gsm medems, it's not gonna work because there may be more than 1000 users using different numbers to send and receive messages ).

Hence what I want to develop is a platform which is capable of sending and receiving sms messages to/from any no. of phone numbers without using gsm modems.

I have browsed through a lot of articles on the internet and lot of them are suggesting to host an sms gateway like [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) and use it with GSM modems.

Can anybody give me some idea on the technology used in the paid sms gateways out there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The paid SMS services have peering agreements with all the carriers and send SMS messages via SMPP directly through each carrier's SMSC (Short Message Service Center).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this is what I want know exactly. Could you please provide a little more information on how I should proceed to make such a setup?